# WKWebView not working for load PDF from remote URL in ios 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, wkwebview

I am using remote URL to display pdf file in webview. It's working fine with UIWebView in ios 12.
But, in iOS 13.0 showing the blank page. Also i tried WKWebview. Both iOS 12 and 13 showing blank page. My pdf url is not .pdf extension

It is look like https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/MYTASKS4/fileupload.ashx?docno=CTBMJV/000001/19&doctype=JournalVoucher&atch=0&empcode=00797

Here is my code

```
     NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"docno=%@&doctype=%@&atch=%@&fname=%@&empcode=%@", gStrTranId,gStrTranNo,gStrAttachmentType,gStrFileName,gStrUserCode];

    body = [body stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];

   NSURL *aUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/MYTASKS4/filedownload.ashx?%@",body]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest new];

    NSDictionary *customHeaders = @{@"Authorization": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",[SESSION getKeyValue]] , @"auth_key": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",[SESSION getAuthorizeCode]], @"Content-Type": @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" };
     
     // set the new headers
     for(NSString *key in [customHeaders allKeys]){
         [request addValue:[customHeaders objectForKey:key] forHTTPHeaderField:key];
     }

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setURL:aUrl];

    self.myWebView1.navigationDelegate = self;

    self.myWebView1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    [self.myWebView1 loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: i am also facing the same issue if you got the solution please post the answer.